# Swipe to Refresh But Swiping Up from Bottom Of Screen? in Jetpack Compose

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I haven't found a question that was exactly what I was asking. The only one I found was from 6 years ago: [Android Swipe Up to Refresh ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32396673/android-swipe-up-to-refresh-listview)

When I reach the bottom of a Column of Text lists, I want to be able to swipe up from the bottom of the screen to refresh and load more content of the list view. Bottom to Up.

I checked the SwipeRefresh library from Google Accompanist, that library only changes the alignment of the swipe, not the swipe direction.
I don't want to have to import someone's library, is there a way to do this without having to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Swipe refresh from bottom of screen in compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71197810/how-to-add-swipe-refresh-from-bottom-of-screen-in-compose)

Comment: @nglauber No, I already saw that post, Accompanist does not have swipe direction, only changes the location of the indicator